# ¿Cómo hacer una función factorial en Python sin utilizar numpy u otro módulo? (ver mi ejemplo)

Tags: python, python-3.x, funciones, algoritmos, revisión-de-código

Estoy jugando un poco con la función para calcular el factorial de un número cualquiera y se me ocurrió crear esto utilizando numpy:

```
import numpy as np

def factorial(x):
    n=[]
    if x==1:
        return 1
    if x>1:
        while x>1:
            x-=1
            n.append(x+1)
    return np.prod(np.array(n))
```

La función corre perfectamente, pero como señalé tuve que recurrir a numpy para hacerlo. Mi pregunta es cómo hacerlo utilizando código base, ya que como saben, el factorial de un número cualquiera sigue la fórmula:

```
n!= n x (n-1) x (n-2) x ... x 1
```

Dado el ejemplo que puse, me gustaría saber si existe, en código base algo equivalente a:

```
np.prod(np.array(n))
```

De antemano muchas gracias.

Comment: No sería más pythonic hacer un generador con yield?

Comment: retiro lo dicho. Pero si quieres hacerlo con yield seria algo como :
https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-write-a-factorial-program-in-Python-using-Yield

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tan facil como

```
def factorial(numero):
    resultado=1
    for i in range(1, numero+1):
        resultado=resultado*i
    return resultado
```

Answer (score 1):

Python tiene la función *suma de secuencias* (`sum`), pero no tiene la *multiplicación*. Un modo de multiplicar secuencia es utilizando `functools.reduce`:

```
from functools import reduce

def factorial(n: int) -> int:
    return reduce(int.__mul__, range(1, n+1))
```

En tu código original, creas una lista que conviertes luego en `np.array`. Es un desperdicio de memoria ya que únicamente necesitas recorrer la secuencia una vez. Es más adecuado usar un *iterador*, lo que viene a ser `range()`.

Answer (score 0):

Hay dos maneras de hacerlo, ya sea usando un loop

```
def facto_2(n):
    for i in range(2,n):
        n*=i
    return n
```

o usando recursividad (la cual te recomiendo que la uses si y solo si no hay otra manera de resolver el problema, ya que es poco eficiente)

```
def facto_1(n):
    return 1 if n==0 else n*facto_1(n-1)
```